# DNSSEC: Why are RRSIGs returned in the "Answer" not "Additional" section?

Tags: dns, dnssec

Looking at Wireshark traces of DNSSEC responses, I see that the RRSIG is returned in the "Answer" section, even though it wasn't part of the query.

Why isn't it returned in the "Additional" Section, which is precisely designed for additional information besides the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the idea is to keep the RRs and their signatures close together.

[RFC 4035, Section 3.1.1, Including RRSIG RRs in a Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4035#section-3.1.1)

> 3.1.1.  Including RRSIG RRs in a Response

When responding to a query that has the DO bit set, a security-aware
authoritative name server SHOULD attempt to send RRSIG RRs that a
security-aware resolver can use to authenticate the RRsets in the
response.  A name server SHOULD make every attempt to keep the RRset
and its associated RRSIG(s) together in a response.  Inclusion of
RRSIG RRs in a response is subject to the following rules:

> 

o  When placing a signed RRset in the Answer section, the name server
MUST also place its RRSIG RRs in the Answer section.  The RRSIG
RRs have a higher priority for inclusion than any other RRsets
that may have to be included.  If space does not permit inclusion
of these RRSIG RRs, the name server MUST set the TC bit.

> 

o  When placing a signed RRset in the Authority section, the name
server MUST also place its RRSIG RRs in the Authority section.
The RRSIG RRs have a higher priority for inclusion than any other
RRsets that may have to be included.  If space does not permit
inclusion of these RRSIG RRs, the name server MUST set the TC bit.

> 

o  When placing a signed RRset in the Additional section, the name
server MUST also place its RRSIG RRs in the Additional section.
If space does not permit inclusion of both the RRset and its
associated RRSIG RRs, the name server MAY retain the RRset while
dropping the RRSIG RRs.  If this happens, the name server MUST NOT
set the TC bit solely because these RRSIG RRs didn't fit.